# Totals with sub-populations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
-----------------
| Name  | Amount|
-----------------
| A     | 100   |
| B     | 200   |
| C     | 100   |
| D     | 200   |
| E     | 100   |
| Total | 700   |
-----------------
```

I want to be able to total up for each individual and show the rest as a total for comparison. So for eg:

```
-----------------
| Name  | Amount|
-----------------
| A     | 100   |
| Others| 600   |
| Total | 700   |
-----------------
```

When I do a `GROUP BY` and `WITH ROLLUP`, I'm able to get the original table, but haven't been able to figure out how to generate the 2nd table.

Comment: Hi, try with this, in your select statement:       SELECT blabla...
     , CASE WHEN Name = 'A' THEN 'A' ELSE 'others' END AS type
...
GROUP BY  type
...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT NAME, AMOUNT FROM
(
SELECT
CASE WHEN A THEN A ELSE OTHERS END AS NAME, AMOUNT
FROM MyTable
) T
GROUP BY ROLLUP NAME, AMOUNT
```